# scraping data from website that could change

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to create an Android App where I can scrape data from a specific website. The informations on that website could change (textual data).Also, I don't know if the HTML structure will change over time. My questions are:

1. Does anyone recommend a specific tool or framework for scraping
   (for free)?
2. How can I know when informations(textual data) get changed on
   the website so that I can update my app ?
3. How to deal with changes on the HTML structure of the website?

This is my first experience in scraping and any answer could help me a lot.
Thank you

Comment: Check if the website provides an API to use. Also check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530285/how-to-know-if-the-website-being-scraped-has-changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A much better way to do this would be to have a server that does the actual scraping of the website then your App will talk to this your server and receive only the data the App needs, this way the App will not break every time the website changes.

As for the server scraping you will need to update your scraping code every time the website structure changes, you will know if it has changed when your scraping code breaks or returns garbage results.

You can know if the website data has changed by scrapping it and comparing the results to the previous results, if the results are new then you allow the App to fetch the new data.

If you do it in the app you will consume a ton of data because you have to download the site every time you want to check for changes. 
Also your app will break maybe even crash when the site structure changes which will frustrate users and it takes a long time for users to receive an App update and some of them will not update at all.

Comment: What is the frequency of my server  so that it can detect the changes? How to be sure that I do not overload the website server?

Comment: @habenah You have to make the decision yourself based on the type of data you are extracting, consider how often the website usually changes and how often you want to update the App users. There is almost no way you could possibly overload the website if you are just using one server to do the downloads one at a time, what type of website can be overloaded by one user? Remember the App users will talk to your server only so they will not be hitting the website, only the server will hit the site.

Comment: Like I said you cant produce too many requests from one server if you do one request at a time, it is the same as one user reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you want to do the scraping from. One of the li raries I use is [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org) it allows you to connect to a URL and fetch the html like so :

```
Connection.Response page = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").method(Method.GET).execute();
Document pDoc = page.parse();
```

You can then parse the page using Jsoup's methods which are quite easy and since Jsoup 1.10 you can use CSS selectors like so :

```
Element element = pDoc.select(".class-in-html-element");
```

You can always do the scraping server side and serve it to your app that way you can make changes to the scraping algorithm once the website changes but if you have too much users you will be making too much requests from the same ip (your servers ip).

I would recommend doing the scraping in the app, but with variables that come from your server. 
For example keep a JSON file on your server with values like `"title_of_scrapped_page":"css_selector_to_use_in_app"` and serve this json to your app each time it starts up. That way you can make changes to the scraping algorithm while doing the scraping in app.

Comment: What is the frequency of my server so that it can detect the changes? How to be sure that I do not overload the website server?

Comment: What do you mean frequency of server ? Are you going to keep a copy of the scrapped data on your server and send it to your app upon request ?

Comment: I mean how many times do I need to run my server so I can detect changes on the website? I need to have a push notification in my app every time a data changes in the website.

Comment: Well it all depends on how often the website changes its content, if the content changes really often, something like facebook you could refresh the data every 5min if its something like youtube for example I guess every 15 min would be ok etc